# Center UILabel Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, addsubview

I have a UIImageView as the background view of my table view. When there is no data for the table, I am adding a UILabel as a subview of the image view. I am having trouble getting the label centered though. The label is always off to the right.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
    backgroundImageView.center = self.tableView.center;

    self.noLocationsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:backgroundImageView.frame];
    self.noLocationsLabel.center = backgroundImageView.center;
    self.noLocationsLabel.text = @"No saved locations";
    self.noLocationsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.noLocationsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.noLocationsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkboard SE" size:24.0];

self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

if (self.locationsArray.count == 0) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

        [self.tableView.backgroundView addSubview:self.noLocationsLabel];
        self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
```

Comment: why are you giving the image view frame to uilabel frame?

Answer (score 1):

If your image frame is say 50,50,50,50, then your label will also be 50,50,50,50, but since it's a subview of the image view, it will never be in the center.  Same concept applies to `center`.  Center is only in respect to the views superview.

In order to make it center you could set the frame like:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,backgroundImageView.frame.size.width,backgroundImageView.frame.size.height);

self.noLocationsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: rect];
```

Or perhaps even:

```
self.noLocationsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: backgroundImageView.bounds];
```

Edit:

You can use `center` on subviews.  But you have to set the correct center.

```
self.noLocationsLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(backgroundImageView.bounds),CGRectGetMidY(backgroundImageView.bounds));
```

[Difference between frame and bounds](http://cocoa.tumblr.com/post/43021164010/an-important-difference-between-frame-and-bounds)

Comment: so you are saying that centre will work for only parent view? @Frankie

Comment: I tried setting the center of the label like you did in your edit but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you log the frame of both your `noLocationsLabel` and your `backgroundImageView`  after it's added as a subview?

Comment: self.tableView: {{0, 0}, {600, 600}}, background frame: {{0, 0}, {600, 600}}, label frame: {{0, 0}, {600, 600}}